# Same Parameter name, different scope, same value. How to deal?

Tags: powershell

```
# cmdlet MyCmdlet.ps1
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Variable1,

    [string]$Variable2
)

Begin {
    Function Function-Name {
        Param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [string]$Variable1,

            [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
            [string]$Variable2,

            [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
            [ValidateScript({[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Variable2)})]
            [switch]$Choice
        )

        # function-body
    }
}

Process {
    Function-name -Variable1 "SomeString" -Choice
}
```

This cmdlet was called like below:

```
.\MyCmdlet.ps1 -variable1 "string1" -variable2 "string2"
```

It returns:

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'choice'. The "[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Variable2) " validation script for the argument with value "True" did not return a result of True.

It seems like the value of `-Variable2` of cmdlet was implicitly passed to the function because of same variable name even without specically mentioning it during the function call inside the cmdlet.

Note: I need the variables to have same name so I can see their similar function in the future. And I use `Begin`, `Process`, `End` in cmdlet just so I can convert it into function and put in inside other scripts.

How can I deal with this?

Comment: Is the point of `[ValidateScript({[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Variable2)})]` 
 to make sure either `$Variable2` OR `$Choice` is provided, but not both?

Comment: No, the value was not implicitly passed. *You* are trying to check the value of `$variable2` in the validation routine for the parameter `$Choice`. Which fails. Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: Yes indeed @gms0ulman and I have got what I want from Mathias R. Jessen's answer. I was looking for this answer but I guess I didn't look hard enough.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers I was trying to create a cmdlet that is standalone, that does not have to dot source so that I in the future, any cmdlet will not affect each other even if any of them got modified. Is there any other easier way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time the `ValidationScript` runs, the local variable `$Variable2` has not yet been created, so you get the value from `$Variable2` in the parent scope.

Use `$PSBoundParameters` instead:

```
Function Function-Name {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Variable1,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$Variable2,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [ValidateScript({[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($PSBoundParameters['Variable2'])})]
        [switch]$Choice
    )

}
```

Comment: Exactly. I didn't see noticed that before. Thank you. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to create a script that could be both invoked directly (as a script) and dot-sourced (so you can call the function in it from other PowerShell scripts), you could do something like this:

```
# Invoke-Something.ps1
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$Variable1,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName='bar')]
    [string]$Variable2,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='foo')]
    [switch]$Choice
)

function Invoke-Something {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Variable1,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName='bar')]
        [string]$Variable2,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='foo')]
        [switch]$Choice
    )

    Write-Host 'invocation: function'
}

if ($MyInvocation.Line.Split()[0] -ne '.') {
    Write-Host 'invocation: directly'
    Invoke-Something @PSBoundParameters
} else {
    Write-Host 'invocation: dot-source'
}
```

Using the above approach you can invoke the script directly:

```
PS> Invoke-Something.ps1 -Variable1 'some' -Variable2 'other'
invocation: directly
invocation: function
```

or dot-source it and invoke the function:

```
PS> . Invoke-Something.ps1
invocation: dot-source
PS> Invoke-Something -Variable1 'some' -Variable2 'other'
invocation: function
```

For this to work you must make all parameters of the script optional, though.

A simplified version of this would not define parameters on the script level and pass `@args` to the invoked function:

```
# Invoke-Something.ps1

function Invoke-Something {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Variable1,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName='bar')]
        [string]$Variable2,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='foo')]
        [switch]$Choice
    )

    Write-Host 'invocation: function'
}

if ($MyInvocation.Line.Split()[0] -ne '.') {
    Write-Host 'invocation: directly'
    Invoke-Something @args
} else {
    Write-Host 'invocation: dot-source'
}
```